# Vue3 - use text input to name a new object

Tags: vuejs3, vuetifyjs3

I've got a component where a list of items (objects from a JSON source) can be added to a new list. Some of those items should be customized upon adding them.

When the user click the add button, a modal appears with a text input. I want to use the text input to modify the name of the cloned object.

It's probably an await/async thing, but I can't quite figure out the implementation. As is, the code does not wait for the text area to be submitted, and treats it as "null".

Object:

```
    {
        "category": "qualities",
        "subcategory": "language",
        "name": "bilingual (specify language)",
        "id": UUID
    }
```

Template:

```
//the list
<li v-for="skill in skillList" :key="skill.id">{{ skill.name }}<span><btn @click="addSkill(skill)">Add Skill</btn>

//the modal, using Vuetify's v-dialog
        <v-dialog v-model="dialog">
        <v-card>
            <v-card-title>Speficic Item</v-card-title>
            <v-text-field v-model.lazy="specific"></v-text-field>
            <v-card-actions>
                <v-btn @click="dialog = false" type="submit">Save</v-btn>
            </v-card-actions>
        </v-card>
    </v-dialog>
```

Script (using script setup with refs):

```
<script setup>
  import { ref } from 'vue'
  import skillList from "@/data/skillList.vue"
  const specific = ref('')
  const dialog = false //this boolean shows or hides the modal

  function addSkill(skill) {
    dialog.value = true
    const newSkill = structuredClone(skill)
    newSkill.name = skill.name + specific.value //i want this to be populated from the text field
    skillList.push(newSkill)
  }
</script>
```

Comment: You're opening a modal to change write a value and right away you are doing it, so there is no value there. Consider making another function where you assign value from text input.

Answer (score 1):

You set the name of the new skill before you change it in the modal. The operation order is wrong.

I don't really understand your goal. For example: Why do you copy you skill to newSkill? But anyway. I have fixed your code. It's working now.

Here is the playground

```js
const { createApp, ref } = Vue;
const { createVuetify } = Vuetify

const vuetify = createVuetify()

const App = {
  setup() {  
   const skillList= ref([{
        "category": "qualities",
        "subcategory": "language",
        "name": "bilingual (specify language)",
        "id": 'UUID'
  }])
  const dialog = ref(false) 
  const newSkill = ref({})
  const addSkill = (skill) => {
    dialog.value = true
    newSkill.value = { ...skill };
    newSkill.value.name = skill.name
  }
  const save = () => {
    dialog.value = false
    skillList.value.push(newSkill.value)
  }
    return  {  
      skillList, newSkill, dialog, addSkill, save
    }
  }
}

const app = createApp(App)
app.use(vuetify).mount('#app')
```

```css
#app { line-height: 1.75; }
[v-cloak] { display: none; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.1.4/dist/vuetify.min.css" />
<div id="app">
<li v-for="skill in skillList" :key="skill.id">{{ skill.name }} <v-btn @click="addSkill(skill)">Add Skill</v-btn> </li>
<v-dialog v-model="dialog">
<v-card>
    <v-card-title>Speficic Item</v-card-title>
    <v-text-field v-model="newSkill.name"></v-text-field>
    <v-card-actions>
        <v-btn @click="save()" type="submit">Save</v-btn>
    </v-card-actions>
</v-card>
</v-dialog>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.1.4/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
```